# gradle build could not resolve dependencies

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to build my android project by gradle command: `gradle assembleDebug --offline`. But the result says 
`Could not resolve com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:25.3.1`. 
This library has already been in `.m2/repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-api/lint-25.3.1.jar` and the project builds successfully inside Android Studio. Any suggestions? Thx in advance.

> build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'java'
    configurations {
        lintChecks
    }
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.tools.lint.lint-checks:25.3.1'
        lintChecks files(jar)
    }       
    jar {
        manifest {
            attributes('Lint-Registry': 'com.android.cy.lint.MyIssueRegistry')
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please, show your build.gradle

Comment: @StasLelyuk build.gradle is added. ty.

Comment: where's `repositories {}` block?

Comment: @StasLelyuk The repositories {} block is set to mavenLocal()

Answer (score 1):

Run your build with `--refresh-dependencies` parameter before using `--offline`. Your dependencies should be presented in the dependency cache during "offline" build.

Comment: It may help, but my development environment cannot connect to the internet so that the building process can only run with "--offline".

Comment: @Yi in this case how you've got downloaded these dependencies before?

Comment: These dependencies are inside Android Studio.

Comment: @Yi The path you've mentioned in your question says completely different.

Comment: Yes..but the folder is just a copy of the Android Studio Gradle folder since I need to running Gradle on the command line.

Comment: +1 for `--refresh-dependencies` . After the long round of "unable to find dependency x" errors, this is a life saver. Would be good if I knew how to invoke that from the IDE (Maybe by cleaning the project and syncing again?!)